# What happens if I get an Eternal Heart when I already have 12 Heart Containers?

Tags: the-binding-of-isaac, wrath-of-the-lamb

We already know that Soul Hearts can stack indefinitely, even with 12 Heart containers. What happens with Eternal Hearts in the same situation? Are they still getting added between Heart containers and Soul Hearts, acting at this point as additional Soul Hearts themselves? What if I get two of those? Do they disappear, become Soul hearts or something completely different?

Comment: Do you have any reason to think heart containers cannot also stack indefinitely?

Comment: @murgatroid99 well, they behave differently from soul hearts. Two eternal hearts normally don't stack, because they create a heart container. It's possible that they change their behaviour when your heart containers are full, but I'm having a hard time testing it, so I wanted to know if it is useful to keep getting them when you already have 12 heart containers.

Comment: My point was: do you have any reason besides appearance to think that it's different when you have more than 12 heart containers?

Comment: @murgatroid99 I had no reason to think that it was different. I asked because I had no experience about what happened with more than 12 heart containers, since I only managed to get 12 of those twice, both times before the DLC came out

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tested this actually. Took a while to grind so the eternal heart card would spawn on basement 1. Everything adds up. Just because you can only see up to 12 containers (of any kind) doesnt mean that is the limit. I had managed to get up to 14 heart containers. That is, 12 full heart containers, and could still refill up to 2 empty non-displayed containers. Then I lost count after getting several Balls of Steel pills @_@

Tl;Dr: There are no limits on how many heart containers you can have, whether they are normal, soul or eternal heart containers. Only 12 first containers are shown tho.